# Magento backend product page left tab issue

Tags: magento-1.9

http://prntscr.com/9hsc54

It's not working for some reason. i click but nothing happens.

Need quick and serious help.

Comment: have you added any custom extension for the Product Attachments? Here  issue is attachment action not found. If your add correct controller action then issue is sold.

Comment: Hello, but it's an extension i've just installed it not more not less it was working before i change the admin url but it doesn't know even if i put the admin url back to default.

Comment: but default magento not provided Attachments functionality